# Why is a cookie stored twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to store in a cookie the state of a certain element on my page, more precisely the expanded or shrunk state of a sidebar.

I have managed to store it properly and it works, but I've noticed that if I refresh the page and toggle the sidebar from the expanded or shrunk state, there is a second cookie added, with the same name, but a new value.

Here is what the log outputs:

```
expanded=false; expanded=true; PHPSESSID=2314324545
```

I needed the cookie so that if the user wanted to go on another page, he could see the sidebar the way he left it in the previous page. Now if I have 2 cookies with the same name, this raises a problem when I am checking its value.

Here is how I have implemented it:

```
$('.expand-button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.pushmenu').toggleClass('expanded');
    $('.navbar-left').toggleClass('expanded');
    $('.navbar-left-2').toggleClass('small')
    if( $(window).width()+scrollbarWidth > 1240){
        $('.container.fluid-content').toggleClass('shrinked')
    }
    if($('.pushmenu').hasClass('expanded')) {
        expandedValue = true;
        document.cookie = 'expanded=' + expandedValue;
        console.log(document.cookie);
    } else {
        expandedValue = false;
        document.cookie = 'expanded=' + expandedValue;
        console.log(document.cookie);
    }
})

$(window).on('load', function() {
        //cookie is already set
    console.log(document.cookie);
    if( document.cookie.indexOf('expanded=true') != -1 ) {
        $('.pushmenu').toggleClass('expanded');
        $('.navbar-left').toggleClass('expanded');
        $('.navbar-left-2').toggleClass('small')
        if( $(window).width()+scrollbarWidth > 1240){
            $('.container.fluid-content').toggleClass('shrinked')
        }
    } else {
        console.log('not doing anything');
    }
})
```

Comment: What makes you think you have two cookies with the same name?

Comment: This log to console: https://db.tt/EZfgwN1G

Comment: That belongs *in your question* (as copy-and-pasted text, absolutely **not** as a link to a dropbox picture).

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are linked to the path and the domain name. You may receive two (or more!) cookies on the server side if each have a different domain name such as:

```
.domain.org
.www.domain.org
```

The order in which you receive the cookies is the least qualified domain name to the most qualified domain name (as shown in that list.)

I suggest you install FireBug (assuming you are using a FireBug compatible browser such as Firefox) and have a look at the cookies in there. You will see the details such as the path and domain name and also the expiration date.

To set the path, just use something like this:

```
blah=value; Path=/
```

Similarly, you can force the domain with:

```
blah=value; Domain=.domain.org
```

You may specify multiple parameters by separating them by semi-colons:

```
blah=value; Path=/; Domain=.domain.org
```

If you are using HTTPS (secure domain), I strongly advice you use Secure too:

```
blah=value; Path=/; Domain=.domain.org; Secure
```

Using FireBug, you can delete some of the cookies. It is up to you to do that, use the first version (.domain.org) or the last (.www.domain.org).

The discrepancy may come from your front end code (JavaScript) AND your backend code (your PHP). One way to see what your server returns, to see whether the Path and Domain are both specified as expected, is to use wget with the -S command line option:

```
wget -S http://domain.org
wget -S http://www.domain.org
```

If you allow both "" and "www", then you must force the domain without the www:

```
; Domain=.domain.org
```

Otherwise you will get those duplicates.